# Symfony2: get Doctrine in a generic PHP class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

In a Symfony2 project, when you use a *Controller*, you can access **Doctrine** by calling `getDoctrine()` on `this`, i.e.:

```
$this->getDoctrine();
```

In this way, I can access the repository of such a Doctrine Entity.

Suppose to have a generic PHP class in a Symfony2 project. How can I retrieve *Doctrine* ?
I suppose that there is such a service to get it, but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can register this class as a [service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) and inject whatever other services into it. Suppose you have GenericClass.php as follows:

```
class GenericClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // some cool stuff
    }
}
```

You can register it as service (in your bundle's `Resources/config/service.yml|xml` usually) and inject Doctrine's entity manager into it:

```
services:
    my_mailer:
        class: Path/To/GenericClass
        arguments: [doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

And it'll try to inject entity manager to (by default) constructor of `GenericClass`. So you just have to add argument for it:

```
public function __construct($entityManager)
{
     // do something awesome with entity manager
}
```

If you are not sure what services are available in your application's DI container, you can find out by using command line tool: `php app/console container:debug` and it'll list all available services along with their aliases and classes.

Comment: This will inject the EntityManager. How can I get a repository through it? In a controller I can get the repository as follows: `$this->getDoctrine()                  ->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:Address');`, and I can also get the EntityManager as follows: `$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()`. However, known the EntityManager, how can I get the repository? If I can, then the answer is your!

Comment: If you look at `getDoctrine` in base `Controller` class it just calls `$this->container->get('doctrine')`. So you can do the same with your service (inject `doctrine` into it). But you can achieve the same by calling `$entityManager->getRepository('...')`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I get a "Missing argument"-warning although the service is registered correctly (I can see it using "console container:debug").

Answer (score 1):

After checking the symfony2 docs i figured out how to pass your service
in a custom method to break the default behavior.

Rewrite your configs like this:

```
services:
my_mailer:
    class: Path/To/GenericClass
    calls:
         - [anotherMethodName, [doctrine.orm.entity_manager]]
```

So, the Service is now available in your other method.

```
public function anotherMethodName($entityManager)
{
    // your magic
}
```

The Answer from Ondrej is absolutely correct, I just wanted to add this piece of the puzzle to this thread.