# functions accessible by multiple php classes (Symfony controllers)

Tags: php, function, symfony, methods, controller

I have a couple functions that are used in multiple controllers in my Symfony project. Instead of copy and pasting them constantly, I'd like to have a separate php file (say functions.php) to store the functions.

I've tried the following:

1) include and require the php file with the functions, but it won't let me use $this->getDoctrine().
I've looked at the following posts for help, but it didn't solve the issue:

[Symfony2: get Doctrine in a generic PHP class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906426/symfony2-get-doctrine-in-a-generic-php-class)

[Symfony2 Use Doctrine in Service Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342031/symfony2-use-doctrine-in-service-container)

2) I've tried making it a class and having the functions as methods then doing:

```
$f = new Functions();
$variable = $f->myMethod();
```

But it returns:

```
The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

Thanks for any help. I really appreciate it.

### UPDATE:

The generic class is `Symfony/src/WikiRoster/MainBundle/Controller/DBFunctions.php`
I just need to be able to use `$this->getDoctrine()` or the like somehow in there now. I've tried using the `services.yml` as suggested in the link above, but no cigar. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or
>   namespace probably has a typo.

This issue happens quite often actually. As the error mentions, there are 2 cases explaining why this error is returned:

- If the namespace of your file is not the same as the path of your file
- If the name of your file is not the same as the name you are using in your class

---

### Example

Let's say you would like to use a GeneralClass in a different class like that:

```
use  Acme\YourBundle\General\GenericClass
```

For this to work, `GeneralClass` needs to be in `Acme/YourBundle/General/`, and you need to:

- use the correct namespace: `namespace Acme\YourBundle\General`
- name your class with the same name: `class GenericClass`

You would have:

```
namespace Acme\YourBundle\General;

class GenericClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // some cool stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I just have to deal with the error:  Using $this when not in object context. Any suggestions other than the link i posted above?

Comment: If you update your question with the name of the general file and its path, I can update my answer according to your specific case. Its a general issue that happens very often :)