# Call to a member function getRepository() on string

Tags: php, symfony

I created symfony service as described here: [Symfony2: get Doctrine in a generic PHP class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906426/symfony2-get-doctrine-in-a-generic-php-class)

Service.yml

```
app.lib.helpers:
    class: AppBundle\Lib\Helpers
    arguments: [doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

Class Helpers

```
class Helpers
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct($entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function checkStatuses()
    {
        $orderId = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Orders')->findAll();

    }
}
```

In controller action

```
$helper = $this->get('app.lib.helpers');
$helper->checkStatuses();
```

But im getting error:

> Error: Call to a member function getRepository() on string

What causes that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be

```
arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
```

in your Service.yml

Answer (score 3):

Your service definition not correct, try this or you can read this for more explain http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html:

```
app.lib.helpers:
    class: AppBundle\Lib\Helpers
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```